# Retrieve multiple checkboxes in Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi below I represented the structure of my current `datagridview`, the last field of the `datagriview` has a checkbox what I have to do is retrieve the id of the row corresponds when the check is made is `true`, how can I do to do this?

**DataGridView Structure:**

> MyId | My Value | checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `Id` of the Selected row or cell, then it's pretty straight forward as @JohnG commented.

Otherwise, if you're not on any selection row or cell, then you can iterate over the DataGridView and locate it using

```
string checkBoxColumnName = "IsMale"; // CheckBox column name
string outputColumnName = "MyId"; // Cell column name you want to value from.

var headerColumn = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Single(c => c.Name == checkBoxColumnName);

var r = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(row => (bool)(row.Cells[headerColumn.Index].Value));
var result = r.Cells[outputColumnName].Value.ToString(); // result as string
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to retrieve ID 
you will have to use the cellValueChanged property to retrieve checked row ID

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
           if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2]) == true)
                {
                    textbox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                }
        }
```